# Android: How to unit test "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I'm having a crash in my app where sometimes a `dialog.show` is called after the activity's lifetime. I know where this happens and would like to unit test every bug that occurred in the app to avoid it to appear again. But how can something like this be (unit?) tested?

Comment: You means how you can test that things using unit testing ?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to unit test the exception because the occurrence is tightly bound to the Activity lifecycle as the exception message suggests - the isolation of the occurrence is practically impossible .

You could employ [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) and try to verify whether the `dialog.show()`  method is invoked before `onSaveInstanceState` call but I would not approach the problem this way. And the tests using Robolectric are no longer unit tests.

I met with a few solutions that eliminated the exception occurrence:

1. You could instantiated an internal queue storing functions deferring the `FragmentTransaction`-related methods execution and recognize whether the activity has called `onSaveInstanceState` at the time the `show()` method is attempted to be executed.
   If the activity is in the `created`/`started`/`resumed` state you could execute `show()` immediately. If not, store the function deferring the `show()` execution and execute them

A few lines of pseudocode below:

```
   if (isCreatedOrStartedOrResumed) {
      dialog.show()
   } else {
      internalQueue.add {
         dialog.show()
      }
   }
```

Has the activity returned to the `resumed` state, execute all pending functions

```
fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   while(internalQueue.isNotEmpty()) {
      internalQueue.poll().invoke()
   }
}
```

This approach is not immune to configuration change though, we lose the deferred invocations once the activity gets rotated.

2. Alternatively, you could use [ViewModel which is designed to retain the activity state across configuration change such as the rotation](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e) and store the deferred executions queue from the 1st approach inside the view model. Make sure the functions storing deferred `dialog.show()` executions are not anonymous classes - you may end up with memory leak introduced.

Testing:

1. The way I would test the dialog displaying gracefully would be the `Espresso` instrumentation tests.
2. I would also unit test view model storing/executing deferred executions. 
   If we consider structuring code using MVP or [MVVM architectural pattern](https://caster.io/courses/android-mvvm-pattern) we could store the deferred executions queue within one of the architecture class members and unit test them too.
3. I would also include [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) as a safety net against memory leaks.
4. Optionally, we could still use `robolectric` and develop integration test verifying:

   - the internal queue deferring `dialog.show()` executions after `onSaveInstanceState` gets called
   - the internal queue executing pending `dialog.show()` executions stored after activity has called `onSaveInstanceState` and returned to the `resumed` state again.
   - the `dialog.show()` executed immediately in case the activity is in `created`/`started`/`resumed` state.

That's all I have at the moment, hope you will figure out the satisfactory tests suite verifying correct dialog displaying based on the approaches suggested.